There is a pcap file containing vp8. How do we extract the vp8 frames from the RTP and put it into playable format to be played by VLC?
There is a pcap file containing vp8. How do we extract the vp8 frames from the RTP, piece them in proper containers and put it into playable format to be played by VLC?
I have tried the following:

Use Wireshark to open the pcap.
Decode as RTP then decode as VP8. There are multiple packets. I am able to see the vp8 payload descriptor, payload header and payload. The packet with vp8 keyframe display vp8 payload descriptor, payload header and payload. The next packet is a marked continuation frame with only  vp8 payload descriptor and payload but no header. The next packet is interframe with  vp8 payload descriptor, payload header and payload and so on.
If the packet is a keyframe or interframe, I extract the payload header and payload. If it is a continuation frame I extract only the payload. II concatenate the extracted bytes sequentially.

Did i extract the correct bytes? Is concatenation the correct way to go?
What do i do after this? Can ffmpeg help me?
Please advise. Thanks
I have also obtained a sample of webm file, extracted its top part and concatenate to my extracted bytes. BUt it is still not playable.
Please advise. Thanks.
